# date time calculation that was 6 hours ago

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-xi

I am using crystal XI and I want to run a report where the admit date was within the last 6 hours of the report runtime. I'm not sure how to calculate this.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your report's record-selection formula:

```
//show all admission dates that have occurred more recently than 6 hours 
//before the current date/time
//replace {table.field} w/ correct value
{table.field} >= DateAdd("h", -6, DataDate + DataTime)
```